# Hosting Python slack bot on azure

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, bots, slack

I have written a slack bot which is written using the official slack python SDK.How should I host it to Microsoft azure?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Did you write the bot as a script that has to keep running or are you using a framework like flask / tornado / django ?
Have you tried to use a VM ?

Comment: I wrote the bot as a script. Right now I'm hosting it on a raspberry pi. I didn't try using a VM.I am not using any python web frameworks.

Comment: Spin up a VM on azure and download the required dependencies to make this script run and keep it running on azure exactly the same way you keep it running on your raspberry pi. That should solve the problem. Only one thing is that you need to open up the Incoming and outgoing ports using the azure portal.

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla Thank you. I will try that

Answer (score 3):

Per my experience, if your bot script using slack python sdk is as a web application, I think you can try to change the script as a WSGI  handler to deployment on Azure WebApp.

For more details, please view the Azure offical [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-python-configure) to know how to configure python with Azure WebApps.

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thank you Peter. Let me study the document and i will let you know my concerns